Solution to Brachistocrone with friction
I want to solve the following equation $$\frac{1+y'^2}{(1+\mu y')^2}=\frac{C}{y-\mu x},$$ where $\mu\in (0,1)$ and $C$ are constants. The function $y$ satisfies $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$. I saw that the change $y'=\cot (\theta/2)$ solves the problem. Using this i ended up with $$y-\mu x=\frac{1}{C}\left(\sin \theta/2+\mu\cos \theta/2\right)^2,$$ but from here i dont know how to conclude the problem.

Where did the $C$ go?

I don't know but it's what appear stated at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html

Differentiating the equation
$$
y-\mu x = \frac{1}{C}\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\mu\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2 \tag{1}
$$
with respect to $\theta$, one obtains
$$
\dot{y}-\mu\dot{x}=\frac{1}{C}\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\mu\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\mu\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right). \tag{2} 
$$
On the other hand, by the chain rule,
$$
\dot{y}=\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{d\theta}=y'\dot{x}=\dot{x}\cot\frac{\theta}{2}, \tag{3}
$$
so $(2)$ becomes
$$
\left(\cot\frac{\theta}{2}-\mu\right)\dot{x}=\frac{1}{C}\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\mu\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\mu\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right) 
$$
$$
\implies \dot{x}=\frac{1}{C}\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\mu\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\frac{\theta}{2}
=\frac{1}{2C}(1-\cos\theta+\mu\sin\theta) 
$$
$$
\implies x(\theta)=\frac{1}{2C}(\theta-\sin\theta-\mu\cos\theta+a). \tag{4}
$$
Now you can use Eq. $(1)$ to find $y(\theta)$.
